# PayPal Payout API limits?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

The PayPal PayOut REST API does not document it's limitations. What is the:

- maximum recipients per payment?
- maximum amount per payment?
- maximum amount per recipient?

Note:

- I've review the online documentation and paypal forum (https://www.paypal-community.com/mts) but it is not mentioned.
- I have also checked stack-overflow and could not find an answer.
- I've read 500 recipients in some places, 15000 in others.

Answer (score 0):

**Max recipients**

API Integration: Up to 15,000 recipients in a single call

**[Max amount per transaction](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/reference/faq/#is-there-a-fee-to-send-payouts)**

> There is no limit on the total amount of the payout. Each individual
>   payment can be no more than $20,000.00 USD or its equivalent in local
>   currency by default. If you need to send higher value payments, please
>   contact your account representative or Customer Service.

**Bonus: Who pays the fee?**

The sender pays the fee. The recipient does not. See the [mass pay/payout fees table](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/merchant-fees/)